# Syntax troubles with dbt, Incorrect type. Expected "Seed configs"

Tags: syntax, dbt

I am learning dbt via the `jaffle_shop` project. I'm trying to set-up the raw data in a `raw` database, and `jaffle_shop` schema in order to call the relevant sources later on.

I am having a bit of trouble with my `seeds` config syntax within my `dbt_project.yml`, what am I doing wrong?

```yaml
seeds:
  - schema: jaffle_shop
  - database: raw
  - name: customers
    config:
      enabled: true
      column_types:
        id: integer
        first_name: varchar(50)
        last_name: varchar(50)
    columns:
      - name: id
        tests:
          - not_null
          - unique
      - name: first_name
      - name: last_name
  - name: orders
    config:
      enabled: true
      column_types:
        id: integer
        user_id: integer
        order_date: date
        status: varchar(100)
      columns:
        - name: id
          tests:
            - not_null
            - unique
        - name: user_id
        - name: order_date
        - name: status
  - name: payments
    config:
      enabled: true
      column_types:
        id: integer
        order_id: integer
        payment_method: varchar(100)
        amount: integer
      columns:
        - name: id
          tests:
            - not_null
            - unique
        - name: user_id
        - name: order_date
        - name: status
```

I am working on VSCode, and using the extension `dbt power user`, perhaps it doesn't recognize the underlined config paramemters?

I tried writing it this way :

```yaml
seeds:
 +schema: jaffle_shop
```

which gives no errors until I add `+database`..

I searched the [docs](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/seed-configs), but I don't see the discrepancy with what I wrote...
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing together two different ways to provide configuration to dbt. See [the docs](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/seed-configs) for configuring seeds, and the more general [page](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/configs-and-properties) on the difference between configs and properties.

1. You can provide general config that applies to all seeds (or a subset of seeds in a specific directory) in your `dbt_project.yml` file. These configs use the `+` syntax and only include a subset of all configuration options. This works because it's a project-level config:

   ```yaml
   seeds:
     +schema: jaffle_shop
   ```

   As of v1.3, these are all of the possible seed configs:

   ```yaml
   seeds:
     <resource-path>:
       +quote_columns: true | false
       +column_types: {column_name: datatype}
       +enabled: true | false
       +tags: <string> | [<string>]
       +pre-hook: <sql-statement> | [<sql-statement>]
       +post-hook: <sql-statement> | [<sql-statement>]
       +database: <string>
       +schema: <string>
       +alias: <string>
       +persist_docs: <dict>
       +full_refresh: <boolean>
       +meta: {<dictionary>}
       +grants: {<dictionary>}
   ```
2. You can provide properties or config for an individual seed using what is now called a "property" file (formerly a `schema.yml` file). These property files can be named anything, as long as they are `.yml` files. It's usually a good idea to put a single resource's properties in a single file, put that file in the same directory as the resource definition, and name it `my_resource.yml`. Or you can group them together, with something like `seeds.yml`. It's these property files that use the syntax that you are trying to place in your `dbt_project.yml` file:

   ```yaml
   version: 2

   seeds:
     - name: customers
       config:
         enabled: true
         column_types:
           id: integer
           first_name: varchar(50)
           last_name: varchar(50)
       columns:
         - name: id
           tests:
             - not_null
             - unique
         - name: first_name
         - name: last_name
   ```